# Maximum subarray - returning container

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, sub-array

I am trying to implement version of Kadane's algorithm which returns subarray. Instead of just returning largest sum I would like to get container.
Based on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) pseudocode I have prepared simple implementation.
However, I would like to avoid using indexes ***best_start*** and ***best_end***.
I can not find a way to fill ***out*** vector step by step using ***push_back***.

Could you give me suggestion how should I change logic of this program?

```
std::vector<int> maxSubArrayWiki(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
    std::vector<int> out;
    int max_sum = INT_MIN;

    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int current_start, best_start, best_end = 0;
    for(const auto& n : nums){
        if(sum <= 0) {
            current_start = i;
            out = {};
            sum = n;
        }
        else {
            sum += n;
        }
        if(sum > max_sum) {
            max_sum = sum;
            best_start = current_start;
            out.push_back(n);
            best_end = i + 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    // is it possible to avoid following? return std::vector<int>(&nums[best_start], &nums[best_end]);
    return out;
}

out:
4 2 1 
expected:
4 -1 2 1
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d120f8f0ab923a6

Comment: I recommend completing the example with a small `main` and appropriate headers. Everything we have to invent or change to make a working example is a opportunity to  insert a new bug (and give you a useless answer fixing that bug) or fix the bug (and close the question as non-reproducible)

Comment: THe essence of Kadane's algorithm is abandoning everything and starting over as soon as the sim becomes negative. That could mean lots of wasted copying. Why do you want this?

Comment: You maintain **two** sums (current and best) but **one** output vector. Which sum does this vector correspond to?

Comment: @user4581301
Min example with required headers is was linked below the code snippet.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., thanks, I didn't think about it. You are right, In case of really large vector, it may be more efficint to use indexes. 
I maintain two sums and one output based on wiki example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem.

Comment: I don't find where that example maintains a subarray. Can you show the exact line?